# Generating IE-version conditional comment block from XSLT

Tags: xslt, conditional-comments

I'm trying to add these conditional comments:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

to an xsl file:

```
<xsl:comment>
      <![CDATA[[if lt IE 7 ]> <head class="ie6"> <![endif]]]>
      <![CDATA[[if IE 7 ]>    <head class="ie7"> <![endif]]]>
      <![CDATA[[if IE 8 ]>    <head class="ie8"> <![endif]]]>
      <![CDATA[[if IE 9 ]>    <head class="ie9"> <![endif]]]>
      <![CDATA[[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <head class=""> <!--<![endif]]]>
    </xsl:comment>
```

There is something wrong with my xsl syntax though. Can anyone see it?

Answer (score 4):

Each of those conditionals would need to be a separate `<xsl:comment>`

```
<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if IE 7 ]> <html class="ie7"> <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie9"> <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment>[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]></xsl:comment>
<html class=""> <xsl:comment><![endif]</xsl:comment>
  <!-- rest of the content goes here -->
</html>
```